# Issue with canvas images not loading until the page is refreshed even after adding an onload function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a web application which uses the HTML canvas elements to draw multiple images on screen which are passed to the browser as a JSON string. 
The JSP page has a loop to create the required number of canvases (1 per image) and are given an element id dynamically using a JSTL loop) Following is my javascript code which draws the image on those canvases.

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfImages; i++)
{
    canvasId = 'canvas' + count;   //canvasId is dynamically assigned values as canvas0, canvas1, etc..
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    test = json[i]["source"];
    img.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + test;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
}
```

This code will not load the images until I refresh the page after it is loaded the first time. After searching for the issue I found out that I need to use an onload function for the images. So I modified the above code as follows. (The lines ending with the comment //modified line are the ones that are different from the previous code)

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfImages; i++)
{
    canvasId = 'canvas' + count;   //canvasId is dynamically assigned values as canvas0, canvas1, etc..
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    test = json[i]["source"];
    img.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + test;
    img.onload=function(){          //modified line
    ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);};   //modified line
}
```

But still the image does not load when the page is first loaded. In addition to that it does not load even if I refresh the page like I did before.

Can someone please show me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Try set img.src after setting img.onload callback function.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded blocking language, current execution can not be interrupted by events. The onload is an event and will not fire until all current execution has ended (ie after the loop has finished) and you only have one variable called `img` that can only hold only value at a time. Generally you should not be declaring functions inside loops. For a kludge fix change the statement in the onload to `ctx.drawImage(this,20,20)`